# How do I correctly use 'else' in a batch file?

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I've been working something, and the point where I'm stuck is this:

> **set** /p !=
>
> **if** %!% == yahoo.com **goto** YAHOO
>
> **if** %!% == facebook.com **goto** FACEBOOK
>
> **if** %!% == mail.google.com **goto** GMAIL
>
> **if** %!% == youtube.com **goto** YOUTUBE
>
> **if** %!% == google.com **goto** GOOGLE
>
> **else goto** ELSE

Btw, this is just an example.
Well, the problem is, the else doesn't work correctly... Idk how I should do it so I hope someone can help...

Comment: Why not just get rid of the else altogether? If the previous if statements don't trigger as true and make the code jump to one of the labels, just `goto ELSE`

Comment: You will find that `!` is a problematic character when delayed expansion is enabled, so it may be better to choose `$` or `#` or `@` even.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code easier to maintain:

```
set /p "site="
for %%A in (
  yahoo.com:YAHOO
  facebook.com:FACEBOOK
  mail.google.com:GMAIL
  youtube.com:YOUTUBE
  google.com:GOOGLE
) do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%B in (%%A) do if "%site%" equ "%%B goto %%C
goto SomewhereElse
```

Even better, you can use the full site address as your label, then your code becomes trivial as long as each label starts at the beginning of the line:

```
set /p "site="
>nul findstr /bc:":%site%" "%~f0" && (goto %site%) || goto SomewhereElse

:yahoo.com
rem code here

:facebook.com
rem etc
```

Answer (score 0):

`ELSE`is key word in batch, do not use it for jump label:

```
set /p "X="
if "%X%" == "yahoo.com" goto YAHOO
if "%X%" == "facebook.com" goto FACEBOOK
if "%X%" == "mail.google.com" goto GMAIL
if "%X%" == "youtube.com" goto YOUTUBE
if "%X%" == "google.com" goto GOOGLE
goto ELSEWHERE
```

You should learn batch before you make batch scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p "X="
if "%X%" == "yahoo.com" (
    echo YAHOO
) else if "%X%" == "facebook.com" (
    echo FACEBOOK
) else if "%X%" == "mail.google.com" (
    echo GMAIL
) else if "%X%" == "youtube.com" (
    echo YOUTUBE
) else if "%X%" == "google.com" (
    echo GOOGLE
) else (
    echo OTHER
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use `Else` the code:

```
set /p !=

if %!% == yahoo.com goto YAHOO

if %!% == facebook.com goto FACEBOOK

if %!% == mail.google.com goto GMAIL

if %!% == youtube.com goto YOUTUBE

if %!% == google.com goto GOOGLE

goto ELSE
```

And goto mail.google.com and all that will not send you to the sites.